# form dropdown not returning values

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, return-value

Any help would be appreciated with a form problem I'm having.  I have searched here to no avail, and probably not searching correctly anyhow.  I have posted at phphelp.com without success.

Basically I have a page that has a dropdown in which the users can select 1,2,3,...10,20,..500,1000 or 'other'.  Selecting anything apart from other returns nothing.  That is the problem.  Selecting 'other' opens a text field within which the user inputs manually a number. This option works and returns the correct value along with the row info in an email.

I wasn't able to post the whole code due to length restrictions but you can follow here:
http://www.phphelp.com/forum/beginners-learning-php/form-problem

Here is the html (stripped):

```
    <?php
    //phpinfo();
    //Start session
    session_start();
    //unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);   
    //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
    //echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: ../Login.html");
        exit();
    }
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

select, option{
    font-size:13px;
}

ol.phpfmg_form{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

ol.phpfmg_form li{
    margin-bottom:5px;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%
}


.form_field, .form_required{
    font-weight : bold;
}

.form_required{
    color:red;
    margin-right:8px;
}

.field_block_over{
}

.form_submit_block{
    padding-top: 3px;
}

.text_box, .text_area, .text_select {
    width:60px;
}

.text_area{
    height:80px;
}

.form_error_title{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}

.form_error{
    background-color: #F4F6E5;
    border: 1px dashed #ff0000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form_error_highlight{
    background-color: #F4F6E5;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ff0000;
}

div.instruction_error{
    color: red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

hr.sectionbreak{
    height:1px;
    color: #ccc;
}

#one_entry_msg{
    background-color: #F4F6E5;
    border: 1px dashed #ff0000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


div.col_label{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    text-align: left;
}

div.col_field{
    margin-left:15px;
    width:-50px;
    float:right;
}

li { background: silver; } 
li:nth-child(odd) { background: white; } 

</style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/siteUtil.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
sfHover = function() {
var el = document.getElementById('Nav1');
if(!/\bnav\b/.test(el.className) && el.tagName == 'UL')
setHover(el);
var ieNavs = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for(i=0; i<ieNavs.length; i++) {
var ul = ieNavs[i]; if(/\bnav\b/.test(ul.className))
setHover(ul); }} 
function setHover(nav) {
var ieULs = nav.getElementsByTagName('ul');
if (navigator.appVersion.substr(22,3)!='5.0') {
for (j=0; j<ieULs.length; j++) {
var ieMat=document.createElement('iframe');
if(document.location.protocol == 'https:')
ieMat.src='';
else if(window.opera != 'undefined')
ieMat.src='';
else
ieMat.src='javascript:false';
ieMat.scrolling='no';
ieMat.frameBorder='0';
ieMat.style.width=ieULs[j].offsetWidth+'px';
ieMat.style.height=ieULs[j].offsetHeight+'px';
ieMat.style.zIndex='-1';
ieULs[j].insertBefore(ieMat, ieULs[j].childNodes[0]);
ieULs[j].style.zIndex='101';
}
var ieLIs = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i=0; i<ieLIs.length; i++) if (ieLIs[i]) {
ieLIs[i].onmouseover=function() {
if(!/\bsfhover\b/.test(this.className))
this.className+=' sfhover';
}
ieLIs[i].onmouseout=function() {
if(!this.contains(event.toElement))
this.className=this.className.replace(' sfhover', '');
}
ieLIs[i].onmouseclick=function() {
if(!this.contains(event.toElement))
this.className=this.className.replace(' sfhover', '');
}}}}

if(window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', sfHover);
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="layout1.css" href="../css/layout1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="theme.css" href="../css/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="color_1.css" href="../css/color_1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="custom.css" href="../css/custom.css">

<script id="widgetbox_lib_subscriber_main" type="text/javascript" async="true" src="../js/Main.js"></script><script id="widgetbox_getwidgetinfo_script_140543b6-862b-4218-8d8a-adbba031261e" type="text/javascript" async="true" src="../js/get_widget.js"></script>

<style id="wrc-middle-css" type="text/css">
.wrc_whole_window{  display: none;  position: fixed;    z-index: 2147483647;    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.9);    word-spacing: normal;   margin: 0px;    padding: 0px;   border: 0px;    left: 0px;  top: 0px;   width: 100%;    height: 100%;   line-height: normal;    letter-spacing: normal;}.wrc_middle_main {  font-family: Segoe UI, Arial Unicode MS, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 14px;    width: 600px;   height: auto;   margin: 0px auto;   margin-top: 15%;    background: url(chrome-extension://icmlaeflemplmjndnaapfdbbnpncnbda/skin/images/background-body.jpg) repeat-x left top; background-color: rgb(39, 53, 62);}.wrc_middle_logo {    background: url(chrome-extension://icmlaeflemplmjndnaapfdbbnpncnbda/skin/images/logo.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;    width: 140px;    height: 42px;    color: orange;    display: table-cell;    text-align: right;    vertical-align: middle;}.wrc_icon_warning {  margin: 20px 10px 20px 15px;    float: left;    background-color: transparent;}.wrc_middle_title {    color: #b6bec7;   height: auto;    margin: 0px auto;  font-size: 2.2em;   white-space: nowrap;    text-align: center;}.wrc_middle_hline {    height: 2px; width: 100%;    display: block;}.wrc_middle_description {   text-align: center; margin: 15px;   font-size: 1.4em;   padding: 20px;  height: auto;   color: white;   min-height: 3.5em;}.wrc_middle_actions_main_div {   margin-bottom: 15px;    text-align: center;}.wrc_middle_actions_blue_button {   -moz-appearance: none;  border-radius: 7px; -moz-border-radius: 7px/7px;    border-radius: 7px/7px; background-color: rgb(0, 173, 223) !important;  display: inline-block;  width: auto;    cursor: Pointer;    border: 2px solid #00dddd;}.wrc_middle_actions_blue_button:hover {  background-color: rgb(0, 159, 212) !important;}.wrc_middle_actions_blue_button:active { background-color: rgb(0, 146, 200) !important;  border: 2px solid #00aaaa;}.wrc_middle_actions_blue_button div {    display: inline-block;  width: auto;    cursor: Pointer;    margin: 3px 10px 3px 10px;  color: white;   font-size: 1.2em;   font-weight: bold;}.wrc_middle_action_low { font-size: 0.9em;   white-space: nowrap;    cursor: Pointer;    color: grey !important; margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px; text-decoration: none;}.wrc_middle_action_low:hover {   color: #aa4400 !important;}.wrc_middle_actions_rest_div {   padding-top: 5px;   white-space: nowrap;    text-align: center;}.wrc_middle_action {    white-space: nowrap;    cursor: Pointer;    color: red !important;  font-size: 1.2em;   margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px; text-decoration: none;}.wrc_middle_action:hover {   color: #aa4400 !important;}body,td,th {
    font-size: 11px;
}
.headingsmaltext {
    font-size: 11px;
}
#page_946f409e-e5c4-481a-ab97-8c570c6ed865 .sf_outer_wrapper .sf_wrapper .sf_main_wrapper .sf_main .sf_region6 .sf_content div #content1 div {
    font-size: 18px;
}
</style>

<script id="wrc-script-middle_window" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">var g_inputsCnt = 0;var g_InputThis = new Array(null, null, null, null);var g_alerted = false;/* we test the input if it includes 4 digits   (input is a part of 4 inputs for filling the credit-card number)*/function is4DigitsCardNumber(val){    var regExp = new RegExp('[0-9]{4}');    return (val.length == 4 && val.search(regExp) == 0);}/* testing the whole credit-card number 19 digits devided by three '-' symbols or   exactly 16 digits without any dividers*/function isCreditCardNumber(val){  if(val.length == 19)    {       var regExp = new RegExp('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}');     return (val.search(regExp) == 0);   }   else if(val.length == 16)   {       var regExp = new RegExp('[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}');        return (val.search(regExp) == 0);   }   return false;}function CheckInputOnCreditNumber(self){  if(g_alerted)       return false;   var value = self.value; if(self.type == 'text') {       if(is4DigitsCardNumber(value))      {           var cont = true;            for(i = 0; i < g_inputsCnt; i++)                if(g_InputThis[i] == self)                  cont = false;           if(cont && g_inputsCnt < 4)         {               g_InputThis[g_inputsCnt] = self;                g_inputsCnt++;          }       }       g_alerted = (g_inputsCnt == 4);     if(g_alerted)           g_inputsCnt = 0;        else            g_alerted = isCreditCardNumber(value);  }   return g_alerted;}function CheckInputOnPassword(self){  if(g_alerted)       return false;   var value = self.value; if(self.type == 'password') {       g_alerted = (value.length > 0); }   return g_alerted;}function onInputBlur(self, bRatingOk, bFishingSite){  var bCreditNumber = CheckInputOnCreditNumber(self); var bPassword = CheckInputOnPassword(self); if((!bRatingOk || bFishingSite == 1) && (bCreditNumber || bPassword) )  {       var warnDiv = document.getElementById("wrcinputdiv");       if(warnDiv)     {           /* show the warning div in the middle of the screen */          warnDiv.style.left = "0px";         warnDiv.style.top = "0px";          warnDiv.style.width = "100%";           warnDiv.style.height = "100%";          document.getElementById("wrc_warn_fs").style.display = 'none';          document.getElementById("wrc_warn_cn").style.display = 'none';          if(bFishingSite)                document.getElementById("wrc_warn_fs").style.display = 'block';         else                document.getElementById("wrc_warn_cn").style.display = 'block';         warnDiv.style.display = 'block';        }   }}</script>


</head>
<body id="page_946f409e-e5c4-481a-ab97-8c570c6ed865">

<div class="sf_outer_wrapper">
    <div class="sf_region1">

    </div>
    <div class="sf_extra1"><span></span></div>
    <div class="sf_wrapper"><div style="display:block;overflow:visible;margin:0;padding:0;"><div class="sf_undocked" style="display:block;height:0;position:absolute;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:visible;width:0;top:0;z-index:999998;left:auto;">
</div></div>

        <div class="sf_region2">
            <div class="sf_navigation"><div class="widget main_nav"><h3 class="widget_header"><span>Main Navigation</span></h3><div class="widget_content"><div style="display:block;">
<ul id="Nav1" class="nav">
```

[submenu code removed, dropdown navigator for site]

```
</ul>
</div></div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sf_extra10"><span></span></div>
        <div class="sf_header_wrapper">
            <div class="sf_extra2"><span></span></div>
            <div class="sf_region3">
                <div class="sf_main_header"><div style="display:block;">Site Name</div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sf_extra3"><span></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sf_extra4"><span></span></div>
        <div class="sf_region4">
            <div class="sf_pagetitle"><div style="display:block;"><h1>ORDER</h1></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sf_extra5"><span></span></div>
        <div class="sf_region5">

        </div>
        <div class="sf_extra6"><span></span></div>
        <div class="sf_extra11"><span></span></div>
        <div class="sf_main_wrapper">
            <div class="sf_main">
                <div class="sf_region6">
                    <div class="sf_content"><div style="display:block;zoom:1"><div id="content1"><div style="display:block;"><div style="display:block;">

<div class="form_description">

</div>

<form name="FormToEmail.php" action="./FormToEmail.php" method="post" >

<ol class="phpfmg_form">
<!--ul id="myList"-->
<li class="field_block" id="field_0_div"><div class="col_label"> <label class="form_field">112-24    CCC-241   Coke        Coke Classic Cans                                   24/355ml  cs</label>  <label class="form_required">&nbsp;</label><div class="col_field"> <select name="112-24 CCC-241 Coke Coke Classic Cans 24/355ml cs" id="field_0" class="text_select" onchange="toggleOtherInputBox(&#39;field_0&#39;,&#39;select&#39;,&#39;field_0&#39;);"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="500">500</option><option value="1000">1000</option> <option value="other">other</option> </select><input type="hidden" name="112-24 CCC-241 Coke Coke Classic Cans 24/355ml cs" id="field_0_other_check" value="0"> <br id="field_0_other_br"><input type="text" name="112-24 CCC-241 Coke Coke Classic Cans 24/355ml cs" id="field_0_other" value="" style="display: none; " class="text_box"> <div id="field_0_tip" class="instruction"> </div> </div> </div></li>
<li class="field_block" id="field_1_div"><div class="col_label"> <label class="form_field">112-24    DCC-242   Coke        Diet Coke Cans                                      24/355ml  cs</label>  <label class="form_required">&nbsp;</label><div class="col_field"> <select name="112-24 DCC-242 Coke Diet Coke Cans 24/355ml cs" id="field_1" class="text_select" onchange="toggleOtherInputBox(&#39;field_1&#39;,&#39;select&#39;,&#39;field_1&#39;);"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="500">500</option><option value="1000">1000</option> <option value="other">other</option> </select><input type="hidden" name="112-24 DCC-242 Coke Diet Coke Cans 24/355ml cs" id="field_1_other_check" value="0"> <br id="field_1_other_br"><input type="text" name="112-24 DCC-242 Coke Diet Coke Cans 24/355ml cs" id="field_1_other" value="" style="display: none; " class="text_box"> <div id="field_1_tip" class="instruction"> </div> </div> </div></li>
```

[many similar rows removed (list of other products)]

Comment: Please format your code. Its hard to read code that are not properly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have repeated field names in your form.

Look at 112-24 CCC-241 Coke Coke Classic Cans 24/355ml cs, for example.

Ensure that you have unique names, otherwise you'll override the values with an empty or hidden field.

Also: it will simplify your life if you select shorter field names (preferably without spaces!)

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I am trying this now.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Worked like a charm, I have no way to thank you yet as I have only 2 reputation.

Comment: <li class="field_block" id="94_div"><div class="col">     <label class="form_field">389 Salt</label> <label class="form_reqd">&nbsp;</label><div class="col_">             <select name="389 Salt" id="94" class="text_select" onchange="toggleOtherInputBox(&#39;field_94&#39;,&#39;select&#39;,&#39;field_94&#39;);">
<option value="1">1</option></select>
<input type="hidden" name="389 Salt" id="94_othr_chk" value="0"> 
<br id="94_other_br">
<input type="text" name="389 Salt" id="94_other" value="" style="display: none; " class="text_box"> 
<div id="94_tip" class="instruction"></div></div></div></li>

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me with the part above. I've been renaming the variables but can't seem to figure out the right combination.  I'd like to get back only one instance of the product name, "389 Salt", followed by the quantity.  Instead I either get two instances with the first, "389 Salt: 1, 389 Salt: 67", or I get nothing.  Basically I would like to get only 1 instance with the text box entry quantity over riding the implicit dropdown.  I had tried adding a "1" or "2" after the variable names.

Comment: The closest I can get is this: if all three instances of the variable have different names, the droodown entry works perfect, but clicking "other" and subsequent text entry returns three lines, the first being "389...: other", the second, "389a...: 1", the third, "389c...: 11"

Comment: If I name the variables, 389, 389a, 389a, the dropdown works well, but the text entry returns an extraneous: "389: other" followed by the correct "389a: 99".  So I'd like to eliminate that extraneous line and optimally get rid of the 389a in favour of returning 389 in either case.  I think I need to suppress the hidden output somehow.

Comment: Just to be clear: ideally, in a form, all names should be unique. And preferably without spaces. "389 Salt" is not exacltly a good name, but as long as you keep it unique, it's good.

If you want to hide the result when you select "Other", then you need to modify the server-side mailer (php, maybe?) to filter out (ignore) the field when the value = 'Other', or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a go.  The reason for the non unique names is that I want that to be returned, so I can import two different salt products into another program that requires them to have their human readable labels.